How can I conceal damage to a coated concrete floor?
I believe this floor is concrete flooring with an epoxy seal or some sort of shiny finish; was dumb enough to think it'd be okay to throw some masking tape on the ground while I did some work and pulled up whatever the finish seemed to be.
The floor is already in pretty rough shape to begin with, but the problem is these straight lines that make everything looks like a perfect square and the contrast is pretty extreme. I am looking for any quick fix to at least darken the spots so they mesh a little bit better with the surrounding floor and just go with the weathered look. I tried some floorwax and it darkened to a good shade but just dried to the same light color. I am looking for anything that could stain the concrete to that sort of effect.



Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question.

I don't have a proper answer, but I'd suggest that matching color and sheen in cases like this is always hard. You might consider chemically stripping whatever that coating is and starting fresh.

You're fighting a losing battle trying to match anything on concrete. Either Paint the entire floor or forget about it. It's a garage. Use it like a garage and over time the scars will blend into a "patina" that looks uniform.
